# Regular expression to match Omnifocus projects exported to taskpaper format

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse Omnifocus projects exported to taskpaper format using a one liner regex but I'm having a hard time capturing the tags, specifically having a capture group per `@` tag.

Here is a taskpaper snippet:

```
- My Project
    - My Sub-Project @parallel(true) @autodone(false) @done(2017-04-01 11:12)
        - Task A: Do (1, 2, 3, @) @parallel(true) @autodone(false) @done(2017-04-01 10:43)
        - Task B: Do (4, 5, 6, @) @parallel(true) @autodone(false) @flagged @done(2017-04-01 10:58)
        - Task C: Read https://stackoverflow.com/ @parallel(true) @autodone(false) @flagged @done(2017-04-01 10:41)
```

and the Python Regular Expression I use:

```
^(\t*)-(.*?)((@\w+\((.*)\))*)$
```

Here is [a link with everything set up as above](https://regex101.com/r/ZQ0nFy/1) to try things.

Comment: You may use one regex step approach only with a PyPi regex module. `re` does not keep the full capture stack, only the last value is kept, others are overwritten upon each iteration.

Comment: [Please check if you can use this](http://rextester.com/WMI97528).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I ended up capturing the whole tags part and finding the tag groups in a second pass, I made this gist if useful: https://gist.github.com/KelSolaar/8df974c66f93f8c4b9de46a0b22584a6
Not shiny code but works for my usage.

Comment: Ok, so you chose to keep to the `re`.

Answer (score 2):

You may match the whole part of the string with the @-groups and then either split or match those parts you need to handle with another nested `re.findall`:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r"^(\t*)-\s*(.*?)((?:\s+@\w+(?:\([^)]*\))?)*)$")
ss = ["- My Project", " - My Sub-Project @parallel(true) @autodone(false) @done(2017-04-01 11:12)", "       - Task A: Do (1, 2, 3, @) @parallel(true) @autodone(false) @done(2017-04-01 10:43)", "      - Task B: Do (4, 5, 6, @) @parallel(true) @autodone(false) @flagged @done(2017-04-01 10:58)", "     - Task C: Read https://stackoverflow.com/ @parallel(true) @autodone(false) @flagged @done(2017-04-01 10:41)"]
for s in ss:
    match = [(m.group(2), re.findall(r'(@\w+)\(([^)]*)\)', m.group(3))) for m in rx.finditer(s)]
    print(match)
```

Result:

```
[('My Project', [])]
[('My Sub-Project', [('@parallel', 'true'), ('@autodone', 'false'), ('@done', '2017-04-01 11:12')])]
[('Task A: Do (1, 2, 3, @)', [('@parallel', 'true'), ('@autodone', 'false'), ('@done', '2017-04-01 10:43')])]
[('Task B: Do (4, 5, 6, @)', [('@parallel', 'true'), ('@autodone', 'false'), ('@done', '2017-04-01 10:58')])]
[('Task C: Read https://stackoverflow.com/', [('@parallel', 'true'), ('@autodone', 'false'), ('@done', '2017-04-01 10:41')])]
```

See a [Python demo](http://rextester.com/UJX16755)

The main pattern details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\t*)` - Group 1: zero or more tabs
- `-\s*` - a hyphen and 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `((?:\s+@\w+(?:\([^)]*\))?)*)` - Group 3 capturing 0+ sequences of

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `@\w+` - a `@` followed with 1+ word chars
  - `(?:\([^)]*\))?` - an optional sequence of

    - `\(` - a `(`
    - `[^)]*` - 0+ chars other than `)`
    - `\)`  - a `)`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Yes it is pretty much what I ended up doing as per this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162267/regular-expression-to-match-omnifocus-projects-exported-to-taskpaper-format/45182602#comment77330314_45162267